# how to convert integer to binary for serial port

Tags: python, serial-port

I am trying to send a value over serial port. I am unsure how to convert it into the correct format. I tried bin() for binary and format() but it didn't work.

```
result = 2
ser.open()
ser.write(b'1')
time.sleep(3)

ser.write(result)                 # wrong format
ser.write("{0:b}".format(result)) # TypeError: unicode strings
                                  # are not supported, please
                                  # encode to bytes: '10'
```

The first write operation sends '1' as binary string. Now I want the variable to be send as binary string as well.

Comment: It is called bytes string. `write()` method accept a bytes string parameter, not a binary representation string parameter. Posting module you are using would help a lot but forget about it.

Answer (score 1):

`write()` requires a bytes object.

```
>>> help(serial.Serial.write)
Help on function write in module serial.serialwin32:

write(self, data)
    Output the given byte string over the serial port.
```

To convert an integer to bytes, call [`int.to_bytes()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes).

```
>>> result = 2
>>> b = result.to_bytes(4, 'little')
>>> b
b'\x02\x00\x00\x00'
>>> # to convert back to an integer
>>> int.from_bytes(b, 'little')
2
```

Answer (score 1):

`write()` method accepts a string parameter. You can convert `result` to string with `str()` builtin function like this.

`result = str(result)`

## **Python 2:**

```
result = 2
ser.open()
ser.write(b'1')
time.sleep(3)

ser.write(str(result))
```

## **Python 3:**

You have to encode string in bytes.

```
result = 2
ser.open()
ser.write(b'1')
time.sleep(3)

ser.write(str(result).encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: In Python 3 strings are different to bytes. OP's code strongly implies he's only Python 3.

Comment: @Reti43 I do not understand you. In Python 3, string is Unicode by default. OP wants just to write string representation of variable. OP does not want to pack integer in bytes, he wants to write it as string.

Comment: Read the error properly. The function does **not** accept a string object, but a bytes object. `TypeError: unicode strings are not supported, please encode to bytes: '10'`

Comment: @Reti43 1. OP do not imply he is using Python 3. It may be Python 2 too with `from future import unicode`. 2. It does not make sense to convert `result` to string representation of bits in bytes. 3. I will update answer for Python 3 too.

Comment: Regardless of whether he's using Python 3, or unicode in Python 2, whch I'll grand you, the underlying point was that you were suggesting a solution with strings when the function (regardless of Python version) explicitly disliked. At least you've addressed that now, so your answer is good. While it's only a minor detail, your answer is somewhat unorthodox because it converts a number into a string and converts that to bytes. An integer with 5 digits will end up having 5 bytes. It's just more direct to translate a number straight to its bytes representation, but that's nitpicking.

Comment: By the way, the OP is using Python 3. This error message is only present in the [Python 3 version of the package](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/serialutil.py#L63). If you search for pyserial 2.7, and look at the source of code serial/serialutil.py, you'll verify that. Your answer for Python 2 is indeed correct though, since they do `bytes = str`.

Comment: @Reti43 Disclaimer: Some readers may see us as arguing but we are just debating on missing bits from the question. OP is not understanding how to write(b'bytes') and you want to get him in trouble with unsigned integers, signed integers, integer value to 1, 2, 4, 8 bytes long integers etc., hahaha. Let him do it this way first. **I agree with you**.

Comment: @Reti43 This [Python 3 version of the package](https://github.com/pyserial/pyserial/blob/master/serial/serialutil.py#L63) is portable for Python 2 and 3. There is a single package for both versions.

Answer (score 1):

Like this :

```
import binascii

def write(num):
    pack = binascii.unlexlify("%04X"%num)
    ser.write(pack)
```

> Important point: Which number system used on device (8,16,32,64 bit) ?
>
> 8 Bit = 1 Byte(0-255)
>
> 16Bit = 2 Byte(0-65535)
>
> 32Bit = 4 Byte(like upside)(0-4294967295)
>
> All ranges are `UNSIGNED`(look up), but `float`
>   got extra definition !

You can't type binary `1` value with keyboard :

`binascii.unlexlify("%01X"%1)` so equal to `\x01` (of course you can use `struct` package)